# Python win32 узнать все атрибуты файла

Tags: python, winapi

Всем привет. Пытаюсь разобраться с библиотекой на питон win32. Хочу узнать весь список атрибутов файла. Но при использовании этой функции и других - выводится только последний добавленный атрибут.
Как с помощью win32 для питона узнать все атрибуты?

пишу код:

```
def attributes(fileName): 
        win32file.SetFileAttributes(fileName, win32file.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY)
        win32file.SetFileAttributes(fileName, win32file.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM)
        att = win32file.GetFileAttributes(fileName)
        print(f"Current attributes: {att}")
```

результат:

> 4

если заменить на

```
att = win32file.GetFileAttributesEx(fileName)
```

, то результат будет такой:

> Current attributes: (4, pywintypes.datetime(2019, 9, 9, 13, 30, 32,
>   221000, tzinfo=TimeZoneInfo('GMT Standard Time', True)),
>   pywintypes.datetime(2019, 9, 9, 16, 19, 25, 397000,
>   tzinfo=TimeZoneInfo('GMT Standard Time', True)),
>   pywintypes.datetime(2019, 9, 9, 16, 19, 19, 138000,
>   tzinfo=TimeZoneInfo('GMT Standard Time', True)), 42)

Comment: Если заменить что? Никакой разницы в коде не заметил.

Comment: Функцию GetAttributes на GetAttributesEx, есть ещё GetAttributesW и GetAttributesExW, но результат тот же - только последний аргумент

Comment: Прошу прощения, в первом варианте опечатка. Исправила

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем коде вы сначала делаете файл только "только для чтения", потом только системным. Т.е. вторым вызовом "перезатираете" то что сделали первым вызовом. `GetFileAttributes` вам показывает правильный результат - файл системный, но не только для чтения.

Функция [`SetFileAttributes`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-setfileattributesa) вторым параметром принимает атрибуты как целое число, в котором каждый бит отвечает за определенный атрибут (битовые "флаги"). Чтобы сделать файл и системным, и только для чтения, атрибуты нужно объединить с помощью битового логического "или":

```
win32file.SetFileAttributes(fileName, win32file.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY | win32file.FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM)
```

Comment: спасибо! Это помогло понять, как выделять атрибуты из числа.